# How do I prove that the SBAF activation function is not a probability density function?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, machine-learning

The SBAF activation function is as follows -
Note : 0<=x<=1
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+ kx^a(1-x)^{1-a}}
$$
Where k and a are constants.
I know we have to show that integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, dx$ is not equal to 1.
But I'm not able to integrate this. 
Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Well, the first problem is that the function gets negative values. That already rules out the possibility of it being a PDF.

Comment: I'm sorry , I forgot to mention 0<=x<=1.

Comment: Also  k and a are positive constants.

Answer (score 0):

$0\leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. So $\int_0^{1}f(x)dx \leq 1$ and equality can hold only of $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. But $f(x) \neq 1$ for any $x \in (0,1)$!.